# Using atomic update in Solr get an error

Tags: solr

I'm getting the following error in 5.2.1:
`RunUpdateProcessor` has received an `AddUpdateCommand` containing a document that appears to still contain Atomic document update operations, most likely because `DistributedUpdateProcessorFactory` was explicitly disabled from this `updateRequestProcessorChain`

I tried working in cloud and in single. Guess that must be something with my `solrconfig.xml` - can someone please post example to a file that works?

In the solrconfig I have the following but also tried other.

```
  <initParams path="/update/**">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="update.chain">add-unknown-fields-to-the-schema</str>
    </lst>
  </initParams>

<updateRequestProcessorChain name="add-unknown-fields-to-the-schema">
    <processor class="solr.UUIDUpdateProcessorFactory">
        <str name="fieldName">id</str>
    </processor>
    <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
    <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />

</updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

When trying the example in http://yonik.com/solr/atomic-updates/ it works fine but that is using dynamic fields.

BTW - got the same error when trying solrj and also curl command (with
xml in a file)

Thanks.

Comment: So do you have an update request chain? (specific either in your config or in the request)

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Please see updated question.

Comment: My first guess is that your (oldish) Solr version doesn't insert `DistributedUpdateProcessorFactory` automagically before `RunUpdateProcessorFactory` as older versions do - try adding that manually :-)

Comment: Tried adding <processor class="solr.DistributedUpdateProcessorFactory"/> before <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" /> but didn't help. Any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that I had the following missing from schema.xml. Strange that didn't read anything about it as a requirement.

```
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was in update json format

```
d = [
        {
            "id": sub,
            "link":{
                "add": {
                    "linked_date": Linked_date, 
                    "collection": super_collection,
                    "super": super_docid
                    }
                }     
        }
    ]
```

but the correct is [] arround "add" value like bellow

```
d = [
        {
            "id": sub,
            "link":{
                "add": [{
                    "linked_date": Linked_date, 
                    "collection": super_collection,
                    "super": super_docid
                    }]
                }     
        } 
    ]
```